# Internal Server Error after adding CMS fields in php file

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have created Homepage.ss for the template and Homepage.php for the page type and after adding some codes to add a field in the php file, i am getting an internal server error message that pops up in a small window at the top right corner of the page and i also couldn’t get to the edit mode nor preview mode of the admin page.

Already flushed the cache and run dev/build also but doesnt work.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of admin when going into the Homepage

[image]

Comment: can someone please tell my why this topic has been marked down?

Comment: At a stab in the dark: you haven't mentioned which version of SilverStripe you're using, you've posted a screenshot of the code instead of the code and it doesn't sound like you've tried to debug the error message you're getting. This means your question is difficult to reproduce. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (a good question) for future reference

Comment: sorry for being such lazy on this. now i get it. i am new to php as i am just a designer with knowledge of web design tools(html,css,javascript,jquery etc.). i guess my knowledge in php is not enough to do projects in silverstripe. now i have to do some work with learning it. anyway, thanks for shedding some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am getting an internal server error message that pops up in a small window at the top right corner of the page

First of all, when you get a system error you will usually be able to do some basic debugging to work out what the actual problem is. This can involve setting the `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` .env var to "dev" so that exception traces are printed (either directly to the screen or in your network requests browser monitor for AJAX requests).

Once you know what the problem is you can work out how to fix it.

---

Your problem is that you aren't handling any of the class namespaces in your code. `Page` and `PageController` exist in the global namespace, but everything else is namespaced. Try this:

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField;

class Homepage extends Page
{
    private static $db = [
        'BottomContent' => 'HTMLText',
    ];

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HTMLEditorField::create('BottomContent', 'Bottom Content'));
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. this has worked like a charm. however, when you want to add a tab for image field like let say a background image for the page. are you required to add a namespace for it again? if so, what namespace should it be? im sorry for being dumb at this but if there's anything that i need to learn before doing this, please let me know. thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's right. You can find the namespace by looking at `UploadField.php` (top of the file), or you can find a plugin for your IDE that will autocomplete the namespaces for you

Comment: im currently using brackets . however, i couldnt find any plugins for it that will resolve namespace automatically. is there something you can suggest as to which IDE has available plugins?

Comment: Php storm would be good, but sublime and atom are also good (and free) with these plugins